# Badges for early watchers of popular tags

Tags: discussion, badge-request

Would it make sense to create a new set of badges for rewarding early watchers of popular tags?

I can think of a few reasons why this may be useful:

1. Encourage people who create new tags to help manage them and build momentum.
2. Encourage people to find tags synonyms.

---

> **Scout** <sup>Bronze</sup>
>   Is one of the first twenty people to watch a tag later watched by 100+ people
>
> **Explorer** <sup>Silver</sup>
>   Is one of the first twenty people to watch a tag later watched by 500+ people
>
> **Pioneer** <sup>Gold</sup>
>   Is one of the first twenty people to watch a tag later watcher by 1000+ people

Comment: I see it encouraging more silly tags, just for a badge.

Answer (score 5):

Why should users be actively excluded from earning badges if their habits around browsing Stack Overflow don't involve them actually watching *any* tags at all?

Badges are supposed to be fairly inclusive, instructive and pose no real barrier to participation, even if some are harder than others (looking at you, Unsung Hero).  By being the first **twenty** of a specific badge, you now get something which is fundamentally impossible to earn for any established tags, and would require new languages or technologies to come up *and* for you to be interested in participating in them.

All for a badge.

No thanks.

Comment: I see what you mean; I didn't look at it from that perspective.

Comment: Even though you're making a valid point, I don't think we can say that this is *actively* excluding people from earning badges. I mean a similar point could be made for "Synonymizer" then; arguably there is a finite amount of synonyms you can make for a given tag. As you said people have different habits which will inevitably lead them away from earning certain badges. Someone who never ask questions is unlikely to earn any question-related badges. If one doesn't want to watch tags, why do you think they would feel excluded from earning these "early watchers" badges?